# selecting dates and time frame

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I select only dates which are greater than 40 days?

```
SELECT name, gender, WardNo, StartOfOccupancy, EndOfOccupancy  
  FROM Patient, Occupancy  
  WHERE EndOfOccupancy > 40 StartOfOccupancy;
```

I want to show data where the person has been in the job for more than 40 days before they ended their occupancy, I have tried numerous varients but can't figure out how to construct the final line and keep getting this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to check the boundary cases to see if you are getting what you want. If you are using Oracle DATE datatype, you may wish to compare TRUNC(EndOfOccupancy) and TRUNC(StartOfOccupancy) to get rid of time components.

```
SELECT name, gender, WardNo, StartOfOccupancy, EndOfOccupancy  
  FROM Patient, Occupancy  
  WHERE TRUNC(EndOfOccupancy) - TRUNC(StartOfOccupancy) >= 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT name, gender, WardNo, StartOfOccupancy, EndOfOccupancy
FROM Patient, Occupancy
WHERE EndOfOccupancy > DATE_ADD(StartOfOccupancy, INTERVAL 40 DAY)
```